# using Python fetch CI attributes from Json file in Servicenow cmdb

Tags: python, cmdb

im in dire need of some logic on how to fetch data from a json file located in my servicenow cmdb, and then store it in cortex xsoar context table

here is part of a github code that does the same, the only difference is it fetches the attributes directly from the dashboard while i need to fetch the attributes from Json file

[ServiceNow CMDB](https://github.com/demisto/content/blob/master/Packs/ServiceNow/Integrations/ServiceNow_CMDB/ServiceNow_CMDB.py)

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can write an automation script to achieve the goal. If you can share a sample I can look into it and provide you with the solution.